# "Nontrivial-to-break" JavaScript data decryption

Tags: javascript, encryption

## Summary/findings/solution:

#### <kbd>▲</kbd> [CryptoJS](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) might be what you're looking for

#### <kbd>▼</kbd> [Browser-targeted JavaScript cryptography is inherently insecure, and should not be relied upon](http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/) <sup><sub>*(From [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439209/nontrivial-to-break-javascript-data-decryption#comment39691675_25439209))*</sub></sup>

---

***Context:***
I want to distribute a list of Web links to specific individuals by sending a file that would be downloaded by the recipient and then stored on their computer or device.
At the same time, I want to provide some level of mitigation against unintended targets from being able to access the data in the file.

***Goal:***
I am aware of encrypted PDF, but since I am significantly more familiar with JavaScript and CSS, and the links will (obviously) require a Web browser to open anyway, **I am interested to know if I can encrypt** the **data** (which would be **a couple of kilobytes** at the *very* most) **and then decrypt it from within the browser, using JavaScript**.

***Requirements:***
I do not mind if I use an encryption-capable compression library, or a encryption-specific algorithm; my sole requirement is that the encryption used is "moderately" nontrivial to bruteforce (it doesn't need to be groundbreakingly secure) and that the data is mathematically/algorithmically useless without the password.

Comment: How do you intend to let the user view the file?

Comment: [RSA in JavaScript](http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/). At least in theory.

Comment: @cpburnz: The data would be base64-encoded into the HTML itself, and once the decompression was run, would be available to JavaScript which would then format it into the rendered page appropriately.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: This looks really interesting, thanks! ***Note**: That page **does** implement JavaScript decryption, albeit ostensibly just for testing (since decryption is **quite** a bit slower than encryption)*

Comment: @i336_ so the encrypted data is stored in the HTML file. Where is the encryption key stored? Or does the user enter the password?

Comment: This depends on your definition of "moderately nontrivial." How about a straight XOR on a password?

Comment: @cpburnz: Yeah, the idea is that without the password, the data is useless.

Comment: @daveͤͮͣͩ: Exactly what do you mean? I have a vague understanding of XORing, but not in a cryptographic context; I must confess that the mechanics of encryption are a subject I need to learn very much about :P

Comment: @i336_ if you have an array of bytes and apply a binary XOR against a password it becomes encrypted. To decrypt apply the XOR against the password again. For best results repeat the password byte array to match the length of the input array. It you're happy with this I can post as an answer.

Comment: @daveͤͮͣͩ: This sounds like it might be quite a bit more practical in terms of speed than RSA. I'm using 8/9-character base58-based passwords elsewhere in my system, so full RSA is kind of a bit much :P *<<[Google: "javascript xor decryption"](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=javascript+xor+decryption) - plenty of hits>>*

Comment: @dave I wouldn't recommend a simple XOR because it is not very a secure if the key is shorter than the data. AES with a CBC block would be much better. See also http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/227/4715

Comment: @cpburnz that's why I said it depends on your definition of "moderately nontrivial"

Comment: @daveͤͮͣͩ, cpburnz: Well, as I noted above, I'm using base58 passwords elsewhere in the system, and pragmatically speaking it would not be that difficult to apply OpenCL brute-force decryption against that data... so *this* part of the system doesn't need to be significantly more secure than that. Is XOR ***that*** bad, in this light?

Comment: I am not a cryptanalyst, but I did find a link on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28955/how-to-break-xor-cipher-with-repeating-key) discussing the topic of breaking XOR encryption.

Comment: Thought I'd check a couple things out and discovered that notwithstanding the fact that I'm using relatively simple passwords in the other parts of my system, I actually happen to be using an encryption system that's AES-256-based (!). I had no idea... and this probably mixes things up a bit. [Googling "javascript aes256 decryption](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=javascript+aes256+decryption) promptly led me to discover **[CryptoJS](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)**, which looks **exactly like what I'm looking for** at this point.

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works for you. I'll reverse positions now to play Devil's advocate and point out that some people think that [any encryption implemented in javascript is considered unsafe](http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/), but only you can decide what level of security is acceptable for your scenario.

Comment: @daveͤͮͣͩ: That was an extremely insightful and nascent read, thanks for that. For what it's worth, in my situation the JavaScript would be running in a locally-downloaded HTML file which would contain all the JS/CSS/other resources required for it to run and display, so {w,sh}ould technically have no reason to make outgoing network connections. This is probably one of the few situations where JS crypto makes sense (but, ironically, because there are no network connections involved...).